# Android: The "OnStop / OnDestroy" dilemma

Tags: android, xamarin, gps

this is a problem I couldn't find a solution to:

My app creates a fake location object. This needs to be destroyed every time the user closes the app. If it isn't it'll stay intact until the whole phone is restarted.

Now, I could put a DestroyLocationObject() function in within the OnDestroy() method, yet - under certain circumstances OnDestroy is never called. Even when the user finishes the app totally.

However, OnStop is always called. 
But the problem is, OnStop will be called, even when the user is NOT wanting to close the app entirely but just put it into the background and then maybe return back later.

How can I make absolutely sure that the location object I build will be destroyed when the app is closed. No matter how it is closed?

Comment: When user puts the app in background, if you do not call finish();, OnPause will be called.

Comment: wait.. explain this a little further please... i dont understand but it seems to be the solution!

Comment: `onStop()` is not guaranteed to be called, either.  `onPause()` is the last teardown method that is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to destroy the object in the onStop() method and create a new one in onRestart()

Comment: thanks! but unfortunately, it isnt: the app needs to create fake location objects while it is in the background

Comment: Ok, well the onDestroy method is not guaranteed to be called. You should check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29 and read up on the onDestroy :)

Comment: @user8013509 You can't depend on activities existing in the background.  If you need to do anything in the background, host it in a `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the way to go is to create the object in `onStart` and destroy it on `onStop`.

This way, even if they put the app in the background, it is re-created when they come back.

The problem with the way you want to do it is that if Android is running low on memory, the System will destroy your app or remove memory objects anyway. Don't assume that when they come, your object will be the same.

Another idea, if you need the same exact location object each time, make the object `Serializable` and save it so you can retrieve it next time.

Answer (score 0):

The only circumstances in which `onDestroy()` is not called are when the user force-closes your app, or when the framework kills your app to free memory.  When either of these things happens, the entire VM is destroyed.  So unless you're holding onto system resources (files, sockets, etc.) there's nothing left to clean up.

Comment: what if you are running a service. from my experience even if app is removed, service might remain running

Comment: @Emil On one hand, that should be impossible. On the other hand, it's plausible that Android 7+ is actually that broken. Google is completely off the rails.

Answer (score 0):

onPause is called when user presses home button. You should put your method (DestroyLocationObject()) in onPause as well.